# Reading in Streams of a Particular Size, smaller than the file size (C)

Tags: c, zlib, fread

Suppose I have a file `file` that is 32.2 MB.  And then I read it in as so

```
gzread(file, buffer, buffer_size);
```

(or perhaps like `fread`).  But suppose I have set `buffer_size = 0x10000`, which is about 65 kilobytes.

Is it so that each time I call gzread, it will go to the next ~65kb chunk?

I am reading through a project with this while loop:

```
while (ks_getuntil(ks, KS_SEP_LINE, &str, &dret) >= 0) { 
    stuff;
}
```

where the `gzread` line is inside of `ks_getuntil`, and `ks` is a data structure where `buffer` is located and where `file` is located (and `buffer_size` is set for the program as a whole already).  It isn't manipulated within the while loop.

This makes it seem that for this to make sense, `gzread` moves in chunks of `buffer_size`, but wasn't sure and thought to check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? Yes, that's what it does. `gzread()` returns how much it read. That will be the amount requested, or less if the end of the file has been reached.

Comment: Sorry I was having issues running it (my problem, sorry)... I understand the basics of how it works, but what I mean, if I have a file with 195 kb, will it read (as written in my question) as 0 - 65kb, then 65kb - 130 kb, then 130 - 195 kb when called like this?  Or will it keep reading 0 - 65kb?